# How to troubleshot full-text population errors in SQL Azure?

Tags: azure-sql-database

In the SQl Server, I can see the full text crawl logs for population errors. Is there anything equivalent in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We understand this is a limitation and working on a solution to surface these errors. Satya - MSFT